# Integrate PowerDNS into Windows DC's DNS, use same domain

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, entra-id, powerdns

We have the following setup:

```
dc01.our.domain 10.10.10.101
dc02.our.domain 10.10.10.102
phpipam.our.domain 10.10.10.250
```

We need all our hosts to use our DC's as the primary and secondary DNS servers, mainly for AD integration. However all other DNS records we want to store in PHPIPAM. PHPIPAM is set up and integrated with powerdns, so that as we build host records in PHPIPAM the powerdns database gets populated.

I want to set up DNS forwarding in our domain controllers to use powerdns if a record is not found.

I also want the SOA and NS records to be the same on powerdns and windows dns, is this possible?

After testing I found its not working very well. And I think its because the Windows server's are authoritative over the `our.domain` domain. So if a record is not found there it stops and returns NXDOMAIN without forwarding to PHPIPAM / Powerdns.

I did create a new domain on powerdns called `test.lab` and built an A record in there. Now when I query `nslookup testhost.test.lab 10.10.10.101` I get the record I expected, so forwarding works.

Mainly the ask for same domains across all DNS servers was because users don't want to have to remember two different domains to lookup systems / know which records are on which domains.

Maybe there is a different solution, but I cant think of one without making a different domain on powerdns and doing a full FQDN query to one of our DC's for the non-authoritative domain.

Any recommendations?

Comment: imho the easiest way to archive is to use pdns as a secondary and gets it's information pushed from the master

Comment: `Mainly the ask for same domains across all DNS servers was because users don't want to have to remember two different domains to lookup systems / know which records are on which domains.` It's called single-label name resolution.

Comment: @djdomi, can you elaborate please? You use the word "secondary" and "master", both general terms. I ask as in PHPIPAM I can make a dns server a "secondary" but I dont know what that does. You could also be referring to "secondary zone ". Can you be more specific in what your suggesting please? Greg doesn't your suggestion require me to adjust every client to use two search domain names to accomplish this?

Comment: Greg's suggestion is maybe possible IMHO - using DHCP and dns domains. The PD is also a NS and is always a MASTER. Any kind of DNS Software could be used as a secondary, as long it is correctly set up.